# libsvm in matlab for multiclass prediction of test data

Tags: matlab, svm, libsvm

when i use the libsvm in matlab for multiclass classification, the svmpredict command consists of also the testing labels. As I dont have the labels for test set, is it possible to predict it somehow using the libsvm in matlab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just provide a meaningless label vector. The only use of the labels is so the prediction function can report some statistics. They are not actually required for prediction in any way.

Comment: how will i get the predicted labels?

Comment: The predicted labels are the output of `svmpredict`.

Comment: is it true even for multi-class classification?

Comment: Yes, this is also true for multiclass classification.

Comment: I get the predict_label values as a vector of zeros always. can you tell me why its not showing labels? why these values are zeros when my labels were from 1 to 7 ?